# I want the Dropbox syncing icons (overlay icons such as not synced, synced )?

Tags: dropbox, shell-icons

I want to know where the Dropbox overlay syncing icons are stored on my windows machine as i build a syncing app like Dropbox and i want to use them.

Comment: You want to retrieve them programmatically? if so then using which language? What operating system are you on? etc.

Comment: No, I want them as files as i am building a syncing app like Dropbox and i want to use these icons when syncing files and folders

Comment: I already created icon overlays in windows and i want to use these icons for my overlay handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/#download) to extract the icons from the `Dropbox.exe` file:

[image]

On a side note: I think you're better off getting icons that are free to use from a website like [IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/) where you can filter by license instead of using the (potentially copyrighted?) ones from DropBox.

Comment: Thank you. That is already what i want; sure , we will create our own icons